# Trouble With C# MVC Ajax request

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

so I am having trouble calling my function in my C# controller. Whenever the ajax request is made, the controller automatically redirects to the main view of the controller, my "Index" method. If I put a breakpoint, the function never reaches my function "Favorite", and instead just redirects. I've been at this for a while, and just don't see what I'm doing wrong. Thanks.

Here is my ajax function:

```
    var updateFavorites = function (event) {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'Post',
            url: baseUrl + '/Post/Favorite',
            data: {
                id: $(this).attr('data-id'),
                isfavorite: $(this).attr('data-favorite')
            },
            success: function () { },
            complete: function () { }
        });
        event.preventDefault();
```

Here is my Favorite method:

```
    [System.Web.Mvc.HttpPost]
    public JsonResult Favorite(int id, bool isfavorite)
    {
        "Code here..."
    }
```

Here is the default view:

```
    public ActionResult Index()
    {  
       "Code here..."
    }
```

Does anyone have any idea what could be happening? I've been staring at my code and trying different things for hours but can't seem to find the bug. Thanks!

Edit:

Here are some things asked for:

Routing Config:

```
    routes.MapRoute("SpecificPost", "Post/{title}/{action}",
            new { controller = "Post", action = "Details", },
            new { title = @".*" });

    routes.MapRoute("Create", "Post/{action}",
            new { controller = "Post", action = "Create", });

        // MVC Default
    routes.MapRoute("Default", "{controller}/{action}", new { controller = "Post", action =   "Index" });
```

Html(this is the button, not sure what else you want):

```
    <span class ="btn favoriteButton" data-id="@Model.Id" data-favorite="@Model.IsFavorite">Favorite</span>
```

Also jquery:

```
    $('.favoriteButton').click(updateFavorites);
```

Comment: I assume Favorites method is in PostController? Can you also add your routing table to ensure nothing is intercepting the route before it can get to the PostController?

Comment: what do you have in your route config file

Comment: is you are doing this through pressing a button, the problem may be that a submit is taking action. Could you please provide the HTML?

Comment: Updated my post to have the code asked for! Thanks!

Comment: make sure your button looks like this <button class="favoriteButton" type="button">yourtext</button>, also you could just leave the url you are calling like this url: 'Favorite',

Comment: If i change the url to that, i get a 404 error now

Comment: Anything else that you need code-wise from me to make this more clear?

Comment: I was able to fix the problem by creating a separate controller for the Favorites. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like the following route definition will ALWAYS redirect to ../Post/Create for any route matching "Post/{anything}"

```
routes.MapRoute("Create", "Post/{action}",
    new { controller = "Post", action = "Create", });
```

You could remove this route definition completely and, as long as the request comes in as Http 'POST', the default route:

```
routes.MapRoute("Default", "{controller}/{action}", new { controller = "Post", action =   "Index" });
```

will correctly route "Post/Favorite" to the PostController.Favorite() action.

Comment: I tried this, but now neither the Favorite nor the Create routes work at all.

Comment: So, this actually solved the Favorite problem, but now I can't get it to redirect to the create page now :(

Answer (score 0):

The problem was within my routes. I had too many routes that were ambiguous so the first route in my sequence was catching everything, making the URL i was trying to use, incorrect. I was able to solve the problem by moving all of the Favorites stuff to a new controller, and calling that controller instead.